# apache spark exception history log already exists

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a set of spark applications one after one on a yarn cluster using oozie ssh actions. Every time a specific spark application starts running it comes back with a failure, and the exception thrown  is :

```
exception in thread "Driver" java.io.IOException : Log directory hdfs://xxx:8020/user/.../applicationHistory/aplication_...._.. already exists!
```

In the stack trace I can see that this exception is thrown after I try to make an instance of SparkContext in my application. 
There is no another application given this specific name by spark, so I don't understand how it is possible that this log already exists.
Does anybody know why is there already a log with this application name?

Answer (score 0):

you can only use Directory for log Path.